# How to make my output like this "Prime number : 499,497...2"

Tags: javascript

So I want to make a program that check number if it's prime number. I wanted to output like this

"Prime number : 499, 497....2."

but I got my output like this

"Prime number : 2"

```
  let i = 500;
  let para = document.createElement('p');


   function isPrime(number){

        if (number === 2) {
            return true;
        }

        if (number <= 1) {
            return false;
        }

        for (let i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(number); i++) {
            if (number % i === 0) {
                return false;
            }
        
        return true;

        }
         
   }

   for (i = 500; i > 0; i--) {


        if (isPrime(i)) {
            para.textContent = "Prime number: " + i;

            
        }
   }
   
let section = document.querySelector('section');
section.appendChild(para);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you overwrite `para.textContent` with each loop and the last loop is 2, so you get "Prime number : 2" at the end. You need to add to the string instead of overwriting it or use an array to collect the numbers.

Something like this should work:

```
let primeArray = [];
for (i = 500; i > 0; i--) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
        primeArray.push(i);
    }
}
para.textContent = "Prime number: " + primeArray.join(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is your loop is resetting the content.
You can accumulate the prime numbers using a filter

```
const primeNumbers = Array.from(Array(500).keys()).filter(isPrime);
para.textContent = "Prime number: " + primeNumbers.join(',');
```

Comment: Ok sir, I will try to do this. Thank you.